# javascript function, won't return to values?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to simplify a javascript function so it's more readable

Currently I'm trying to change this function below.

```
export default function generateSentimentLineGraphPoints(items) {
  /**
   * Generate array of 24 Zeros
   */
  let values = Array.apply(null, Array(24)).map(Number.prototype.valueOf, 0);
  const nOfEntries = Array.apply(null, Array(24)).map(
    Number.prototype.valueOf,
    1
  ); 
.....
}
```

to more simply use this function,

```
function generateTime() {
  /**
   * Generate array of 24 Zeros
   */
  let values = Array.apply(null, Array(24)).map(Number.prototype.valueOf, 0);
  const nOfEntries = Array.apply(null, Array(24)).map(
    Number.prototype.valueOf,
    1
  );
  return values, nOfEntries;
}
```

with,

```
function generateTime() {
  /**
   * Generate array of 24 Zeros
   */
  let values = Array.apply(null, Array(24)).map(Number.prototype.valueOf, 0);
  const nOfEntries = Array.apply(null, Array(24)).map(
    Number.prototype.valueOf,
    1
  );
  return values, nOfEntries;
}
```

This isn't working for some reason - i'm not sure why, it won't load the graph properly. Any ideas?

Comment: I think it needs more code to clarify. How are you using the old and new functions ? What graph are not loading ? Did you get any error message? Also, another thing is that JS does not allow returning multiple values, so you either return the 2 values as an object `return {values, nOfEntries}` and use destructing when calling the function: `let {values, nOfEntries} = generateTime()`, or return as an array `return [values, nOfEntries`] and caling it by: `let [values, nOfEntries] = generateTime()`. See this link for more info: https://www.javascripttutorial.net/javascript-return-multiple-values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`return values, nOfEntries;` returns the value of `nOfEntries`, it doesn't return `values` at all. A JavaScript function can only return **one** thing. You're using the comma operator there, which evaluates its left-hand operand (`values`), throws away the result, then evaluates its right-hand operator (`nOfEntries`) and takes that result as the operation result.

To return multiple values, wrap them in an array or object:

```
return [values, nOfEntries];
```

or

```
return {values, nOfEntries};
```

---

Side note: That code to create an array filled with a given value is unnecessarily complex. Back in the day it probably should have just been a function that uses a loop, but these days you can use `Array.prototype.fill`:

```
let values = Array(24).fill(0);
```

Comment: Is there a simpler way to do the nOfEntries code as well?

Comment: @LeCoda - The original code is exactly the same as for `values` but with `1` instead of `0`, so...